# How to dynamically create buttons in cells with Google Apps Script for Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to add buttons on a set of rows in a spreadsheet, and each of those buttons will call a function using that row's values.

Is this possible with Google Apps Script/Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now neither Google Spreadsheets nor GAS support controls in cells. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876819/) here and a possible workaround for this issue.