# How to call a script in Google Spreadsheet above a frozen row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Above a frozen row I want to put an image that is linked to a script; e.g. click the image and a script runs.

- I can insert an image and add a script to it, problem: can only be
  done under frozen row.
- I can insert an image using =image("imageurl";2), I can even put a
  hyperlink to this =hyperlink("url"; image("imageurl";2)) and this
  works nicely but I can't call a script.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do you add UI inside cells in a google spreadsheet using app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876819/how-do-you-add-ui-inside-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet-using-app-script) ... shows how to insert a drawing and link it to a script. Unfortunately, as you've found, floating images are not allowed in frozen rows or columns, so that technique breaks down if you must freeze rows. A quick search on the interwebs will show that this has been a long-term complaint about Google Sheets. ([For instance](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/t8IyqODh058).)

There are options, none of them ideal:

- Use a custom menu function instead. That means users need to hunt a bit to find the menu option to kick your script, but it does stay in view no matter where they are.
- Use the hyperlink & image work-around you've described, but use a published script url as the target. That will allow you to run a google apps script, indirectly.
- Use a sidebar. OK, this isn't actually supported in Sheets yet - visit [Issue 3162](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3162) and star it for updates.