# getRange() increment by 12

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to google script and have not coded for 15 years. Computer Science 2, Java …

So my question is: How do I increment my `get.range()` by 12 each time.

```
function clearRange() {   
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DK LU Tracker');   
   sheet.getRange('B4:B12').clearContent();   
   //sheet.getRange('B16:B24').clearContent();   
   //sheet.getRange('B28:B36').clearContent();   
   //sheet.getRange('B40:B48').clearContent();   
   //sheet.getRange('B52:B60').clearContent();   
   sheet.getRange('B64:B72').clearContent();   
   //sheet.getRange('B76:B84').clearContent();   
   //sheet.getRange('B88:B96').clearContent();   
   //sheet.getRange('B100:B108').clearContent(); }
```

That's what it is looking like and I know there is a more efficient way. Then I want to create a button and add it to my Google sheet. Attach this script to the button and voilà! Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the individual `clearContent()` calls with one call within a for loop.  For example:

```
  for (i = 0; i <= 96; i = i + 12)
      sheet.getRange(4 + i, 2, 9).clearContent();
```

With this version of `getRange()`, the parameters are row number, column number, and number of rows, in that order.

To create a button, follow the steps from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6966272/1840239).