# Google Sheets - How can I make a cell that calls on a macro?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The end goal is to have a cell at the end of a bunch of columns that will contain a button or hyperlink or checkbox that will tell the sheet to copy that whole row into another tab.

1. My first thought was to create a button in each row, but according [to this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876819/how-do-you-add-ui-inside-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet-using-app-script), there is no way to anchor a button into a row and thus all information about that row would be lost when a user clicks the button.
2. My second and very painful thought was to create a hyperlink that sends an API payload to a GoogleSheetAPI demon I have written that manages these sheets with the row information. The hyperlink would contain the row information in the URL encoding. That would tell the demon to copy that row and put it in the input row.

The second seems so hackey and I feel like I'm missing something. Can I make a hyperlink that calls on a macro or function which will pass the row number?

Comment: You can have a cell at the end of the row that you use to either trigger the action, or to identify the row to send if you still want to use a button. You can easily create an [`onEdit()` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) to watch for specific cells and values in those cells.

Comment: @I'-'I It's an excellent suggestion, but for my user base I need it to be, ummm, let's say...fantastically easy?

Comment: You want to run a script by clicking a cell. If my understanding is correct, for example, how about using the check box? The flow is as follows. 1. Create a checkbox to a cell. 2. At the script, create ``onEdit()`` function as an event trigger. 3. When the checkbox is turned on (or off), the script you want is run. I think that the script can be controlled by the coordinate of the cell with the checkbox. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.