# How can I create a button using app script and assign a script to it?

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

As per my understanding if I want to create a button in google sheets, I have to access draw and create a shape like button, then link it to the script i have as it's described in [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781785882517/2/ch02lvl1sec19/creating-a-clickable-button) and in [How do you add UI inside cells in a google spreadsheet using app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876819/how-do-you-add-ui-inside-cells-in-a-google-spreadsheet-using-app-script)

I've three questions,

1. Is there a way to create a button and its `onClick` function inside app script ?
2. If I used the method above (drawing, assigning ...) is this will be accessible to others who are going to use the same script (as i'm creating an Add-on)
3. What's is the use of `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button`?

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want a drawn button in your add-on instead of using a custom menu or HTML interface? A drawing would be editable by the end user, thus breaking your add-on.

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I'm asking for another way rather than drawing.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/html-interfaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. But not with drawing.  You can use any external images as buttons. Use [`sheet.insertImage()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageurl,-column,-row) and [`assignScript`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#assignScript(String)) on the returned overGridImage.
2. Yes.
3. No such method. But you can use [alerts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#alertprompt,-buttons)

Comment: So by adding image as a button, this will be accessible to other users right, and they won't be able to modify it ?

Comment: @Doom Any user with edit access can modify it or even remove it

Comment: Aha, so i think making menus is safer and easier, but i wondered if i can make something that's visible to users on the sheet rather than menus and do the same functionality.

Comment: @Doom You can check if the button is modified or just add the button `onOpen`, if not present. Yes menus are better.

Answer (score 0):

```
function buttonOnADialog() {
  var html='<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Title");
}
```

Comment: Would you explain to me this : "google.script.host.close()"

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host